# When Outlook 2007 ignores css, how to specify font-size?

Tags: outlook, html-email, outlook-2007

I have two Windows computers, both with Outlook 2007.  I send both an HTML email with stuff like:

```
<div style='font-family:Times New Roman,Serif;font-size:11pt'> ...
```

I need it to be Times New Roman, 11pt font. In one Outlook it shows up correctly as Times 11pt, in the other, Arial 12pt.  I can get the second one to display Times by using surrounding content with a tag like:

```
<font face='Times New Roman' size='3'>...
```

But the size is mapped to 12pt, and size=2 is 10pt. I see no way yet to specify the size in px or pt. This tag is disturbing because we're in the year 2013.

I understand that Outlook HTML email rendering is a disaster because it defers to Word instead of IE for rendering. But why the difference? And can I do something to get the second copy of Outlook to act like the first one? Or is there some other way to tell it: "11pt".

Here is my most recent attempt at the HTML sent to Exchange...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body, div, p, table, td {
         font-family:TimesNewRoman, "Times New Roman", Times, Serif;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style='font-family:TimesNewRoman, "Times New Roman", Times, Serif;font-size:11pt;'>
   <font style="font-family: TimesNewRoman, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000;">
    <p>Blah blah.
    </p>
   </font>
 </body></html>
```

Comment: What version of IE is installed on each of those machines? Perhaps it does use IE in some cases?

Comment: IE 8 and IE 7. IE 7 is the machine that requires the <font> tag. How can I tell if it's using Word for the viewer or not? I read that Outlook 2007 did so.

Comment: I think you're right, according to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933793 it is uses Word only which "does not support some CSS". But as a test can u install IE8 on the second machine?

Comment: I can't change that machine. It belongs to a customer.

Comment: Then I think the only choice is not to use CSS, but `<font>` tag and its attributes

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, but I only have Office 2010, so I can't verify that this would work for 2007. In case it helps, I've shared the basic structure of my HTML for Outlook messages below. The key differences I see from the original question are the style type "text/css" and the enclosing comment tags around the styles.  Note that other elements, like td, th, table, etc., can be styled in this block as well.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>My Title</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--

body { font-size: 10pt font-family: sans-serif; }

-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
blah, blah
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure why MS feels the need to go against the standard all the time, but yes - commenting out the styles means Outlook 2010 will still render them. What is this, I don't even...

Answer (score 2):

Times isn't a font in Windows (I believe that is the Mac name for Times New Roman).

Courtesy of [cssfontstack](http://cssfontstack.com/), Try something like this:

`font-family: TimesNewRoman, "Times New Roman", Times, Baskerville, Georgia, serif;`

Beyond this try using the quotation marks fallback in the example above to see if that makes a difference. Also, apply your css styles to a `<font>` tag or a `<td>` directly. Div's are not really recommended for html email, so I'd avoid them wherever possible. I use font tags almost exclusively to style text and they always seem to come through for me.

Comment: Ack. You're right, but my code here was not a copy of the real code. There I did use Times New Roman. I'll update the question.

Comment: Now that we cleared that up, I added more to my answer - see above.

Comment: My issue now is the size.  `<font face='Times New Roman' ...>` works. But an attribute like `style='font-size:11pt'` on the `font` tag is ignored. Mmm... maybe I can try size='2.5' to get 11pt.  Will post again if that works.

Comment: Try something like this format, but with the quotes: `<font style="font-family: TimesNewRoman, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; font-size: 14px; color: #000000;">Here is your styled text</font>`

Comment: Tried it. It rendered at Arial 12pt. Grr.  Updated question with full HTML example.

Comment: Hi. Did you ever get the answer to this question? It's impractical to add `<font>` tags to every..single...line...of....text.  Surely there's a better way to do this?

Comment: I think we got it to behave well enough with a font tag around the entire body, or large chunks of it. So you don't need one every line, but still... ugly. I don't think we ever got exactly 11pt.